# What does GROUP BY -ing on a date with +1 do?

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm analyzing the code of someone else and stumbled on a query like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY date_field + 1
```

What's the difference between this query and one such as the following?

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY date_field
```

If the result to both queries is the same, are they different in terms of performance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just try to check the output from the different queries `EXPLAIN SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY date_field`

Comment: an extra operation, certainly means a difference. But you should look at the execution plan to see exactly what is the cost of the +1.

Comment: The +1 query is not ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: @jarlh - base on what are you saying this?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, "What's the difference between this query and one such as the following?", and I pointed out one difference.

Comment: @jarlh - Why do you think the +1 query is not ANSI SQL compliant?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz,IWD 9075-2:2015(E), 7.12 <group by clause>: <grouping column reference> ::=
<column reference> [ <collate clause> ]

Comment: @jarlh - Thanks. I would have expected that a feature supported by most of the vendors, if not all of them, would get into the standard.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, actually this is not that bad, because it forces people to write better code. If you want to group by a complex expression, instead wrap that part up in a derived table - which is less error prone!

Comment: EXPLAIN doesn't go into any more details: "3) We do an all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate from TABLE by way of an all-rows scan with no residual conditions, grouping by field 1 ((TABLE.date_field)+1)." Removing the +1 from the query gives the same step, but without the "+1" in the text, so no precise explanation there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference logically.  The original code probably has something like:

```
select date_field + 1, . . .
from . . .
group by date_field + 1;
```

The `group by` key then directly matches the expression in the `select`.  However, this is not necessary.  SQL supports expressions on the `group by` keys, and `+ 1` does no affect the outcome.

It *might* affect the execution plan, however.  I am not overly familiar with the optimization engine in Teradata, but two things come to mind:

- The engine may not recognize that it could use an index on `date_field`.
- The engine may get confused on statistics for the aggregation column, choosing a suboptimal aggregation algorithm.

Comment: I simplified the problem for the sake of the question, but yes, it does have the same operations made on date_field in the SELECT and in the GROUP BY (actually add_months(date_field+1, 1) -1 so it can retrieve the last day of next month when date_field is the last day of a month). The results are the same, the execution plan doesn't show significant variations, and the query execution time is the same. I guess this answer has high probabilities of being right, so I'll accept it.